# How can i optimize my code so that it can run much more efficiently?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a small simulation where at the current stage i can click somewhere on the screen and color will spread out like a wave. currently it does that, but my system is that it checks each and every squares up, down, left, and right square to see if its red. if it is, make that square red. Then it saves that x,y and does it a bunch more, then it prints all x,y values to the screen all at once. the problem is, every time it does this it keeps all the values in it and has to do more if checks and slows down a lot. is there a better system I can implement that would be better?
if I want to move each pixel out progressively then i cant thing of any other way than checking pixel by pixel. I also cant just hardcode the pixels because I could click anywhere on the screen. Is there a way to make a wave simulation that does not have to check each and every pixel?

```
import pygame
import sys
width=300
height=300
pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode( (500, 500) )


size=1

tfx=1
tfy=1
increment=1
red=[]
surface.fill( (255,255,255) )
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pygame.draw.rect( surface, (255,0,0), (pos[0],pos[1], size, size) )
        
   
    #pygame.draw.rect( surface, (255,0,0), (width/2-tfx/2, height/2-tfy/2, size, size) )
    

   #!!!!!! this block of code checks every single pixel on the screen to see if the pixel
    #to the right is red and so on. Alternative method in progress that checks in a 1x1 3x3 5x5 square

    
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            
            if x+size <=width-1   :
               color = surface.get_at((x+size,y))
               if  color[1]==0:
                   if  surface.get_at((x,y))[1] !=0:
                    red.append((x,y))
                   #pygame.display.update()

            if x-1 >=0:
               color = surface.get_at((x-1,y))
               if color[1]==0:
                   if  surface.get_at((x,y))[1] !=0:
                       red.append((x,y))
                   
            if y-1 >=0:
               color = surface.get_at((x,y-1))
               if color[1]==0:
                   if  surface.get_at((x,y))[1] !=0:
                        red.append((x,y))
            if y+1 <=height:
               color = surface.get_at((x,y+1))
               if color[1]==0:
                   if  surface.get_at((x,y))[1] !=0:
                        red.append((x,y))


    
    








    
    for i in range(len(red)):
        
        
        pygame.draw.rect( surface, (255,0,0), (red[i][0], red[i][1], size, size) )


    pygame.display.update()

    #print( surface.get_at((97,99)))

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 mb, thanks. can i just copy and paste my whole question or? ive never been there before

Comment: @MattDMo fax, sorry

Comment: @MattDMo, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: @MattDMo [Don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/269301). Don't redirect it either, please.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks for the link. I may have read it years ago, but I didn't save it at the time. I typically tell people to read the site's help center first, but I guess I forgot to here (no sure, comment's been deleted). This link will help a lot.

Comment: Can you remember the position the "wave" starts at, and just draw growing co-centric rings around that point?  You're processing a lot of "space" in the image for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way to get acceptable performance (with pygame) is to use [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) and [`convolve()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.convolve). Create a mask size of the screen:

```py
mask = pygame.mask.Mask(screen.get_size())
```

Create a convolution mask with the following pattern:

```
[False, True,  False]
[True,  True,  True ]
[False, True,  False]
```

```py
convolution_mask = pygame.mask.Mask((3, 3))
convolution_mask.set_at(p) for p in [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]]
```

Set a bit in the mask on mouse click:

```py
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    mask.set_at(event.pos)
```

Create a convolution with the convolution mask in each frame:

```py
mask = mask.convolve(convolution_mask , offset=(-1, -1))
```

Convert the mask into a surface and `blit` it on the screen:

```py
surface = mask.to_surface(setcolor = (255, 0, 0), unsetcolor = (255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
```

---

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

mask = pygame.mask.Mask(screen.get_size())
convolution_mask = pygame.mask.Mask((3, 3))
[convolution_mask.set_at(p) for p in [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)]]

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mask.set_at(event.pos)

    mask = mask.convolve(convolution_mask, offset=(-1, -1))

    surface = mask.to_surface(setcolor = (255, 0, 0), unsetcolor = (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Kingsley's suggestion of remembering storing the wave origin, here's an example that draws circles of increasing radius as time goes by. It will support about five-hundred *waves* before the frame rate drops on my PC. It isn't drawing filled circles so you can see all the waves, but that should be an [easy modification](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html#pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle).

```
import pygame
import pygame.gfxdraw
import time
import math

pygame.init()
width, height = 500, 500
# don't draw circles too large for the screen
max_radius = max(width, height) / math.sin(math.pi / 4)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


class Wave:
    """Class to store the origin position and time of a wave"""

    def __init__(self, position, color=pygame.Color("red")):
        self.pos = position
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.color = color

    def get_radius(self):
        """Returns the number of deci-seconds since creation"""
        return round(10 * (time.time() - self.start_time))

    def draw(self, screen):
        radius = self.get_radius()
        if radius < max_radius:
            x, y = self.pos
            pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen, x, y, radius, self.color)


waves = []
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            wave = Wave(event.pos)
            waves.append(wave)
    ## Clear screen
    screen.fill("white")
    ## draw waves
    for wave in waves:
        wave.draw(screen)
    ## Update display
    pygame.display.update()
    ## Set window title
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"Waves: {len(waves)}, FPS: {clock.get_fps():.1f}")
    ## Limit frame rate
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

Example:

[image: Circles]